# Spark application erroring out because driver outofmemory even though lot free memory still available

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

Can someone please help me to figure out my simple spark application is requiring huge driver memory? Even though I allocated about 112GB, my application fails at about 67GB.
Thanks in advance

The spark driver is using huge memory for running simple application

- Allocated about 112G of memory for running my application when do spark-submit
- At start of the job, I see below message in the logs

```
1019 [main] INFO org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore  - MemoryStore started with capacity 67.0 GiB
```

- My application fails with this error message

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: dag-scheduler-event-loop has already been stopped accidentally.
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.post(EventLoop.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.taskStarted(DAGScheduler.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager.prepareLaunchingTask(TaskSetManager.scala:539)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager.$anonfun$resourceOffer$2(TaskSetManager.scala:478)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager.resourceOffer(TaskSetManager.scala:455)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.$anonfun$resourceOfferSingleTaskSet$2(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.$anonfun$resourceOfferSingleTaskSet$2$adapted(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:390)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.$anonfun$resourceOfferSingleTaskSet$1(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:390)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.resourceOfferSingleTaskSet(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.$anonfun$resourceOffers$20(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:587)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.$anonfun$resourceOffers$20$adapted(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:582)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.$anonfun$resourceOffers$16(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:582)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.$anonfun$resourceOffers$16$adapted(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:555)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.resourceOffers(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint.$anonfun$makeOffers$5(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.org$apache$spark$scheduler$cluster$CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$$withLock(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:955)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint.org$apache$spark$scheduler$cluster$CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint$$makeOffers(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.$anonfun$process$1(Inbox.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
59376410 [dispatcher-CoarseGrainedScheduler] INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl  - Cancelling stage 1
59376410 [dispatcher-CoarseGrainedScheduler] INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl  - Killing all running tasks in stage 1: Stage cancelled
59376415 [dispatcher-CoarseGrainedScheduler] ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop  - DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop failed; shutting down SparkContext
```

scala code snippet

```
val df = spark.read.parquet(data_path)
df.rdd.foreachPartition(p => {
  // code to process the code...
})
```

Job Submit

```
spark-submit --master "spark://x.x.x.x:7077" --driver-cores=4 --driver-memory=112G --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0 --conf spark.rpc.message.maxSize=2047 --conf spark.driver.host=x.x.x.x --class myclass.processor --packages "..,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.3.1" --deploy-mode client
```

Comment: can also share the code snippet .. just wanted to see how you are processing data.

Comment: ```
      df.rdd.foreachPartition(p => {
          val processor = new MyProcessor(
            configs,
            processorStats,
            500,
            false)
          processor.init()
          try {
            processor.processPartition(p)
          }
          finally {
            processor.close()
          }
      })
```